# Can't set value of button inside td during "onload" when using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, button, set, onload

I've encountered some problem.

I have a table(created in html) with few cells when each cell has inside another table and inside each of the cells of inner table there is a clickable button.
By default - there is no text on these buttons(set to be "").

But when I try to set, during "onload", a value(some text) for these buttons, the value remains "".

To access the button I use:

(((document.getElementById("table1").rows[i]).cells[j]).value="go".

*table1 - is an ID of first inner table.

But still the value on the button remain "", and no change done to html web-page.
I've checked in chrome console, and I do get to the right cell, but the value doesn't change.

I would really appreciate any help with this :)

Comment: seems like you are selecting the cell not the button. plz show the markup and a little bit more code (at least the 2 loops)

Comment: The problem was solved by using (((document.getElementById("table1").rows[i]).cells[j]).firstChild.value="go". :) But another problem is that sometimes it work and sometime return UNDEFINED... Use the same browser - Chrome. Don't know where is the problem...